# gl_PointSize changing with devicePixelRatio?

Tags: three.js, webgl, particles

I'm working on particles via threejs and i don't get the same result on different devices. On other screens the point size look smaller, same on my smartphone, in vertical orientation only. While i saw the issue in several different screens I only tested the following experiments with my laptop + smartphone.

[image: Correct look for certain screens] [image: bad look on others]

***Left*** *: correct look with the actual code on certain screens & on my smartphone in horizontal orientation.* ***Right*** *: incorrect look with the actual code on other screens & my smartphone in vertical orientation.*

I first thought it had something to do with `window.devicePixelRatio` but `alert(window.devicePixelRatio)` prints the same number (`3`) in my smartphone with both orientations, though the rendering is only correct in the horizontal one.

I further tried :

- `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)` : renderings in both orientation show 3 times smaller sizes, and still different.
- passing `window.devicePixelRatio` to the vertex shader to write something like `gl_PointSize*=devicePixelRatio`, in addition to the previous idea, gets this  size issue back at its initial state.

**How can one make particles look the same on every screens ?**

Whole code at http://codepen.io/Astrak/pen/BoBWPB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After resizing enough windows i understood `gl_PointSize` somehow represents an absolute size while in my example i want it to be proportional to `window.innerHeight`. I added this value in the shader : `gl_PointSize*=innerHeight` which solved the issue.